# How to validate checkboxes like a quiz in jsp?

Tags: validation, jsp

I am using checkboxes to get multiple answers for a question. I know up until the usage of .get Parameter Values() but I do not know how to validate each option if they are correct.

```
<p>3. Select items that are part of JSP scripting elements</p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="element1" name="ansq3" value="documentation">
    <label for="element1">documentation</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="element2" name="ansq3" value="directive">
    <label for="element2">documentation</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="element3" name="ansq3" value="declarative">
    <label for="element3">declarative</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="element4" name="ansq3" value="expression">
    <label for="element4">expression</label><br>
```

For this question, the supposed correct answers are the last three options...

Comment: You can use `request.getParameter("ansq3")` to get the user input.

Comment: Yah, that's only applicable for radio buttons. .getParameterValues() is for checkboxes.

Comment: The request.getParameterValues just get which checkbox is checked by user only. What do you mean "validate each option"? do you want to loop through all the checkbox and check which checkbox is checked?